# meaning of the phrase "legal no man's land" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have come across it in [Crash Course Media Literacy](https://youtu.be/TVaZnxYKKdM). It is at 19 second. Here is the context:

> Have you ever shared a GIF from your favourite movie or instagrammed some meme you found online. In that moment did you ever think about where that content came from and if you were allowed to use it. Did you consider that it may actually be illegal to share it. Or at least in some **legal no man's land?**

I am aware of the meanings *no man's land* has, but I cannot get what the host means by that. Perhaps he means that although it may be illegal to share the content, at least it is legal in some no man's land. I am not at all sure.

Comment: What you are misunderstanding here is the function of the word **legal** in "legal no-man's land".  The adjective defines the context of that figure-of-speech.  If someone is not following a recipe for a cake, but is making impromptu decisions by the seat of their pants, so to speak, they might find themselves in a "baking no-man's-land", where things are not at all clear. A synonym is "gray area", where things are not clearly black or white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No man's land" originally meant "disputed ground between the front lines or trenches of two opposing armies.". It became a figurative expression meaning "an indeterminate or undefined place or state.". If an act is in a "legal no man's land" then it is not certain whether it is legal or illegal, or if it is illegal, under which statute. Another term for this situation is "grey area" (gray area in US). Grey is neither black nor white.

Answer (score 0):

Actions that are a crime in country A may be legal in country B. Salient example: drug laws in the US and the Netherlands. To judge whether an action is legal, you have to know, in patriarchy-speak, in what mans land you are. Amsterdam, or the US Embassy there? Some regions on earth would make determining the applicable laws very hard, as they are for different reasons effective no-mans lands.

Figuratively, this can be transferred to questions about non-geographic domains: is this picture art, a trademark, or poltical speech? Is it maybe even religiously important? This has similar effects as being in no mans land: You cannot easily decide what laws apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is about copyright laws. Breaching them may not be a crime, but requires a civil action in the courts. It may not be possible to prove legal ownership. In that case it is in **No Man's Land**, so anyone can use it — if they dare, since you know the [original meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_man%27s_land). But it does not mean that it is legal in that territory. It is uncertain.